# Google thinks that the pages for a business in each city are duplicate

Tags: duplicate-content, canonical-url

I have a directory of businesses.  Some of those businesses have many branches in different locatios.

For example:

```
Restaurant A
|
 ---- Branch in City 1
 ---- Branch in City 2
 ---- Branch in City N
```

Each business location has its own page with different address and contact info.

Google is seeing all of those pages as duplicate content.  It is reporting that they have duplicate title and asking me to canonicalize them to one page.  This is despite that they all have different titles containing the location.

Any idea how I can make Google recognize that they are different pages for different branches (and not duplicate content)?

Comment: How much content is the same between the pages?   While it is fine to have some overlap, if you have 5 paragraphs of duplicate text on each of those pages and only the address and city are different, that isn't going to satisfy Google.  I recommend trying to make 50% of the text on any page unique.   See [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)